# condition by which a vector function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ produces area zero

Tags: functions, vector-spaces

I have what seems (to me, although I'm a nonmathematician) an interesting condition to try to describe; it's sort of the nonlinear analogue of singular two-dimensional matrices.

Suppose I have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ that is continuous but maps coordinates $\mathbf{r}_{xy} = (x,y) \rightarrow \mathbf{r}_{uv} = (u,v)$ subject to some condition I am trying to understand.

This condition ensures that for any closed curve $C_{xy}$ defined parametrically as the continuous function $\mathbf{r}_{xy}(t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$ where $\mathbf{r}_{xy}(0) = \mathbf{r}_{xy}(1)$, if the area enclosed by the curve

$$ \iint \limits_{C_{xy}} dx \,dy \neq 0$$

then the area enclosed by the corresponding curve $C_{uv}$ defined by $\mathbf{r}_{uv}(t) = f(\mathbf{r}_{xy}(t))$ produces an area 0:

$$ \iint \limits_{C_{uv}} du \,dv = 0$$

Some trivial examples of this sort of function are:

$$ (x,y) \rightarrow (u=apx+aqy+b, v=cpx+cqy+d) $$

in other words, squashing down $(x,y)$ to a single dimension $w=px+qy$ and then mapping $w$ into the $uv$-plane, with simple trivial cases

$$ (x,y) \rightarrow (u=x, v=0) $$

$$ (x,y) \rightarrow (u=0, v=y) $$

$$ (x,y) \rightarrow (u=0, v=0) $$

I am guessing (but not 100% sure) that $f(\mathbf{r}) = g(h(\mathbf{r}))$ where $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and  $h : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are both continuous, also satisfies this condition. I am also not sure what kind of $f(\mathbf{r})$ satisfies this condition but is *not* expressible as $f(\mathbf{r}) = g(h(\mathbf{r}))$.

**Is there a more concise way to characterize this condition on** $f$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of a map $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ records the infinitesimal change of volume of $f$. There's a [change of coordinates formula for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables): to change coordinates using $f$, multiply by its Jacobian:

$$\int_{f(X)} \phi(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_X \phi(f(y))\ \mathrm{Jac}_f(y)\,\mathrm dy.$$

All of your examples have Jacobian equal to zero, which is the criterion you're looking for.

This means that everywhere infinitesimally, the total derivative is a singular matrix, and so $f$ "crushes volume" into nothing. If you use such an $f$ to change coordinates, you'll always get zero, as you discovered.

Comment: cool, thanks for the clearly-written answer! I'm familiar with the Jacobian, just hadn't thought about it in this way.